# Python's re module - saving state?

Tags: python, regex

One of the biggest annoyances I find in Python is the inability of the `re` module to save its state without explicitly doing it in a match object. Often, one needs to parse lines and if they comply a certain regex take out values from them by the same regex. I would like to write code like this:

```
if re.match('foo (\w+) bar (\d+)', line):
  # do stuff with .group(1) and .group(2)
elif re.match('baz whoo_(\d+)', line):
  # do stuff with .group(1)
# etc.
```

But unfortunately it's impossible to get to the matched object of the previous call to `re.match`, so this is written like this:

```
m = re.match('foo (\w+) bar (\d+)', line)
if m:
  # do stuff with m.group(1) and m.group(2)
else:
  m = re.match('baz whoo_(\d+)', line)
  if m:
    # do stuff with m.group(1)
```

Which is rather less convenient and gets really unwieldy as the list of `elif`s grows longer.

A hackish solution would be to wrap the re.match and re.search in my own objects that keep state somewhere. Has anyone used this? Are you aware of semi-standard implementations (in large frameworks or something)?

What other workarounds can you recommend?
Or perhaps, am I just misusing the module and could achieve my needs in a cleaner way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wish the module had a state-keeping form, too. But I don't consider it hackish to create your own object that keeps state. Seems like a clean, localized and well-defined solution to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying out some ideas...

It looks like you would ideally want an expression with side effects.  If this were allowed in Python:

```
if m = re.match('foo (\w+) bar (\d+)', line):
  # do stuff with m.group(1) and m.group(2)
elif m = re.match('baz whoo_(\d+)', line):
  # do stuff with m.group(1)
elif ...
```

... then you would clearly and cleanly be expressing your intent.  But it's not.  If side effects were allowed in nested functions, you could:

```
m = None
def assign_m(x):
  m = x
  return x

if assign_m(re.match('foo (\w+) bar (\d+)', line)):
  # do stuff with m.group(1) and m.group(2)
elif assign_m(re.match('baz whoo_(\d+)', line)):
  # do stuff with m.group(1)
elif ...
```

Now, not only is that getting ugly, but it's still not valid Python code -- the nested function 'assign_m' isn't allowed to modify the variable `m` in the outer scope.  The best I can come up with is **really** ugly, using nested class which is allowed side effects:

```
# per Brian's suggestion, a wrapper that is stateful
class m_(object):
  def match(self, *args):
    self.inner_ = re.match(*args)
    return self.inner_
  def group(self, *args):
    return self.inner_.group(*args)
m = m_()

# now 'm' is a stateful regex
if m.match('foo (\w+) bar (\d+)', line):
  # do stuff with m.group(1) and m.group(2)
elif m.match('baz whoo_(\d+)', line):
  # do stuff with m.group(1)
elif ...
```

But that is **clearly** overkill.

You migth consider using an inner function to allow local scope exits, which allows you to remove the `else` nesting:

```
def find_the_right_match():
  # now 'm' is a stateful regex
  m = re.match('foo (\w+) bar (\d+)', line)
  if m:
    # do stuff with m.group(1) and m.group(2)
    return # <== exit nested function only
  m = re.match('baz whoo_(\d+)', line)
  if m:
    # do stuff with m.group(1)
    return

find_the_right_match()
```

This lets you flatten nesting=(2*N-1) to nesting=1, but you may have just moved the side-effects problem around, and the nested functions are very likely to confuse most Python programmers.

Lastly, there are side-effect-free ways of dealing with this:

```
def cond_with(*phrases):
  """for each 2-tuple, invokes first item.  the first pair where
  the first item returns logical true, result is passed to second
  function in pair.  Like an if-elif-elif.. chain"""
  for (cond_lambda, then_lambda) in phrases:
    c = cond_lambda()
    if c:
      return then_lambda(c) 
  return None


cond_with( 
  ((lambda: re.match('foo (\w+) bar (\d+)', line)), 
      (lambda m: 
          ... # do stuff with m.group(1) and m.group(2)
          )),
  ((lambda: re.match('baz whoo_(\d+)', line)),
      (lambda m:
          ... # do stuff with m.group(1)
          )),
  ...)
```

And now the code barely even **looks** like Python, let alone understandable to Python programmers (is that Lisp?).

I think the moral of this story is that Python is not optimized for this sort of idiom.  You really need to just be a little verbose and live with a large nesting factor of else conditions.

Comment: LOL and ++ about the Lispy code. Well thought out :-) But I would be strongly unhappy with any programmer who writes real code like this ;-)

Comment: @eliben - heh, thanks.  could have been worse.. at least I didn't try to use call/cc!

Answer (score 5):

You might like [this module](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/456151/) which implements the wrapper you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I like the basic concept of the recipe linked to, but it could be improved if you are using a more recent version of Python. I'm strictly 2.5+ so I'm going to go play hacky-hack now.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a utility class to do the "save state and return result" operation.  I don't think this is that hackish.  It's fairly trivial to implement:

```
class Var(object):
    def __init__(self, val=None): self.val = val

    def set(self, result):
        self.val = result
        return result
```

And then use it as:

```
lastMatch = Var()

if lastMatch.set(re.match('foo (\w+) bar (\d+)', line)):
    print lastMatch.val.groups()

elif lastMatch.set(re.match('baz whoo_(\d+)', line)):
    print lastMatch.val.groups()
```

Comment: This is an interesting concept. Hmm, it can handle a lot of the cases where Python's inability to use assignment in an expression hurts.

Answer (score 1):

```
class last(object):
  def __init__(self, wrapped, initial=None):
    self.last = initial
    self.func = wrapped

  def __call__(self, *args, **kwds):
    self.last = self.func(*args, **kwds)
    return self.last

def test():
  """
  >>> test()
  crude, but effective: (oYo)
  """
  import re
  m = last(re.compile("(oYo)").match)
  if m("abc"):
    print("oops")
  elif m("oYo"): #A
    print("crude, but effective: (%s)" % m.last.group(1)) #B
  else:
    print("mark")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  import doctest
  doctest.testmod()
```

`last` is also suitable as a decorator.

Realized that in my effort to make it self-testing and work in 2.5, 2.6, and 3.0 that I obscured the real solution somewhat. The important lines are marked #A and #B above, where you use the same object to test (name it `match` or `is_somename`) and retrieve its last value. Easy to abuse, but also easy to tweak and, if not pushed too far, get surprisingly clear code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the great answers to this question, I've concocted the following mechanism. It appears like a general way to solve the "no assignment in conditions" limitation of Python. The focus is transparency, implemented by silent delegation:

```
class Var(object):
    def __init__(self, val=None):
        self._val = val

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self._val, attr)

    def __call__(self, arg):
        self._val = arg
        return self._val


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import re

    var = Var()

    line = 'foo kwa bar 12'

    if var(re.match('foo (\w+) bar (\d+)', line)):
        print var.group(1), var.group(2)
    elif var(re.match('baz whoo_(\d+)', line)):
        print var.group(1)
```

In the general case, this is a thread-safe solution, because you can create your own instances of `Var`. For more ease-of-use when threading is not an issue, a default Var object can be imported and used. Here's a module holding the Var class:

```
class Var(object):
    def __init__(self, val=None):
        self._val = val

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self._val, attr)

    def __call__(self, arg):
        self._val = arg
        return self._val

var = Var()
```

And here's the user's code:

```
from var import Var, var
import re

line = 'foo kwa bar 12'

if var(re.match('foo (\w+) bar (\d+)', line)):
    print var.group(1), var.group(2)
elif var(re.match('baz whoo_(\d+)', line)):
    print var.group(1)
```

While not thread-safe, for a lot of simple scripts this provides a useful shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.8 has now provided us with a neat solution: `:=` (the [walrus operator](https://realpython.com/lessons/assignment-expressions/)).

It will assign the right-hand value to the left-hand variable, then return the value.

Basically, we can finally fulfill @aaron's wish and simply write:

```py
if m := re.match('foo (\w+) bar (\d+)', line):
  # do stuff with m.group(1) and m.group(2)
elif m := re.match('baz whoo_(\d+)', line):
  # do stuff with m.group(1)
elif ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest solution is to return early so you can get back to creating variables instead of needing to make an immediate test.

```
def get_results(line):
    m = re.match('foo (\w+) bar (\d+)', line)
    if m:
      # do stuff with .group(1) and .group(2)
      return result
    m = re.match('baz whoo_(\d+)', line)
    if m:
      # do stuff with .group(1)
      return other_result
    # etc.
```

This way you avoid excessive nesting.