# Alternative to the `match = re.match(); if match: ...` idiom?

Tags: python, idioms

If you want to check if something matches a regex, if so, print the first group, you do..

```
import re
match = re.match("(\d+)g", "123g")
if match is not None:
    print match.group(1)
```

This is completely pedantic, but the intermediate `match` variable is a bit annoying..

Languages like Perl do this by creating new `$1`..`$9` variables for match groups, like..

```
if($blah ~= /(\d+)g/){
    print $1
}
```

From [this reddit comment](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/92ewt/experiment_adding_re_to_python_string_objects/c0b7895),

```
with re_context.match('^blah', s) as match:
    if match:
        ...
    else:
        ...
```

..which I thought was an interesting idea, so I wrote a simple implementation of it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6
import re

class SRE_Match_Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, match):
        self.match = match

    def __exit__(self, type, value, tb):
        pass

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.match

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == "__exit__":
            return self.__exit__
        elif name == "__enter__":
            return self.__name__
        else:
            return getattr(self.match, name)

def rematch(pattern, inp):
    matcher = re.compile(pattern)
    x = SRE_Match_Wrapper(matcher.match(inp))
    return x
    return match

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Example:
    with rematch("(\d+)g", "123g") as m:
        if m:
            print(m.group(1))

    with rematch("(\d+)g", "123") as m:
        if m:
            print(m.group(1))
```

(This functionality could theoretically be patched into the `_sre.SRE_Match` object)

It would be nice if you could skip the execution of the `with` statement's code block, if there was no match, which would simplify this to..

```
with rematch("(\d+)g", "123") as m:
    print(m.group(1)) # only executed if the match occurred
```

..but this seems impossible based of what I can deduce from [PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)

Any ideas? As I said, this is really trivial annoyance, almost to the point of being code-golf..

Comment: "almost to the point of being code-golf" disagree.  This is totally code golf.  Can't see what's "annoying" about setting a variable to represent state change.

Comment: I did say I was being pedantic..

Comment: Similar discussion already on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447086/pythons-re-module-saving-state

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting `Python 3.8`, and the introduction of [assignment expressions (PEP 572)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) (`:=` operator), we can now capture the condition value `re.match(r'(\d+)g', '123g')` in a variable `match` in order to both check if it's not `None` and then re-use it within the body of the condition:

```
>>> if match := re.match(r'(\d+)g', '123g'):
...   print(match.group(1))
... 
123
>>> if match := re.match(r'(\d+)g', 'dddf'):
...   print(match.group(1))
...
>>>
```

Answer (score 12):

I don't think it's trivial.  I don't want to have to sprinkle a redundant conditional around my code if I'm writing code like that often.

This is slightly odd, but you can do this with an iterator:

```
import re

def rematch(pattern, inp):
    matcher = re.compile(pattern)
    matches = matcher.match(inp)
    if matches:
        yield matches

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for m in rematch("(\d+)g", "123g"):
        print(m.group(1))
```

The odd thing is that it's using an iterator for something that isn't iterating--it's closer to a conditional, and at first glance it might look like it's going to yield multiple results for each match.

It does seem odd that a context manager can't cause its managed function to be skipped entirely; while that's not explicitly one of the use cases of "with", it seems like a natural extension.

Comment: Yeah, it would work if the `__enter__` code was executed inside the `try` part that gives the `__exit__` code control over the exceptions (because the `__enter__` code could then throw a special type of exception that is swallowed by the `with` statement, effectively stopping any code inside it from executing.) Right now, I don't see a way to get around that though.

Comment: It'd be nice if Python allowed assignment in expressions, like C: "if x = y():", "if not (x = y():"; it'd handle this straightforwardly.

Comment: +1: This is the only viable solution for saving one line of code. While using a generator isn't very intuitive, it does the job and is both scope- and thread-safe.

Comment: @Glenn: Yup, that was my first instinct then I remembered Python doesn't do that `=P`

Comment: I do not understand this `if matches:` thing. I see that match object can be `true` or `none`. Why does python make it confusing ? Why not return just true/false instead ? If you have more than binary choices, then return -1,0,1 etc.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev match() returns a MatchObject, giving access to things like matching groups.  If it doesn't match, it returns None.  It's simple and straightforward, and I suggest reading the documentation.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match

Answer (score 3):

Another nice syntax would be something like this:

```
header = re.compile('(.*?) = (.*?)$')
footer = re.compile('(.*?): (.*?)$')

if header.match(line) as m:
    key, value = m.group(1,2)
elif footer.match(line) as m
    key, value = m.group(1,2)
else:
    key, value = None, None
```

Answer (score 1):

I have another way of doing this, based on Glen Maynard's solution:

```
for match in [m for m in [re.match(pattern,key)] if m]:
    print "It matched: %s" % match
```

Similar to Glen's solution, this itterates either 0 (if no match) or 1 (if a match) times.

No sub needed, but less tidy as a result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using `with` is the solution in this case. You'd have to raise an exception in the `BLOCK` part (which is specified by the user) and have the `__exit__` method return `True` to "swallow" the exception. So it would never look good.

I'd suggest going for a syntax similar to the Perl syntax. Make your own extended `re` module (I'll call it `rex`) and have it set variables in its module namespace:

```
if rex.match('(\d+)g', '123g'):
    print rex._1
```

As you can see in the comments below, this method is neither scope- nor thread-safe. You would only use this if you were completely certain that your application wouldn't become multi-threaded in the future and that any functions called from the scope that you're using this in will *also* use the same method.

Comment: Be careful of this.  It'll break if the code inside the conditional reuses the "rex" object, so to be safe in that case you'd need to make a copy when you use it--and that's mostly undoing the benefit.  It's also not threadsafe unless you jump some TLS hoops; match() on an re object (should be) completely threadsafe.  I think these issues far outweigh the benefits of doing it this way--it's a lot to have to keep in mind to save one line of code.

Comment: For some cases I belive the benefits outweigh the issues. For simple single threaded programs I believe this approach is OK. However "match = re.match(...); if match: ..." is idiomatic python. I'll keep doing it that way myself. Still +1 to @Blixt's answer, for an elegant, perl-like answer to the original question.

Comment: The example given was Perl's magic variables, and they have the same limitations. I can't see any other "nice-looking" way to make the code any shorter than fetching the object and checking if it's not `None`.

Comment: Elegant and Perl-like are precisely opposite descriptions.

Comment: Well for the sake of argument, you could probably have the `rex.match` function keep track of which frame it was executed in and then have a `rex.group` function that would return the group appropriate to the frame it was called from. This isn't something I've tested though and I doubt it would be worth the effort.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://paste.blixt.org/119661 It's far from perfect, but it works across different frames. I haven't worked with multi-threading in Python so I don't know if they have separate frames per thread, I'm just making a huge assumption here. Anyways, I would never recommend using this code, but it's interesting to look at nevertheless. Since the state object is discarded, multiple calls to `match()` will of course overwrite the old set of groups.

Comment: @Blixt: threading.local would be an easier approach. And far more elegant. See http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.local

Comment: Well, to be honest, I don't think any of these solutions should be looked into at all. To save one line of code, only a simple solution should be considered. I don't even think it's worth to make my code thread-safe, because if you want thread-safe code, you should work with objects, and as has been proven, the only way to assign and check an object in one statement is the workaround Glenn posted using a generator, which isn't very intuitive at all.

Comment: Obviously, there's always a balance of complexity vs. benefit, but it's not saving just one line of code; it's saving one redundant line of code in every place you use a regex, which can be a lot in some applications.

Comment: threading.local doesn't help reusing the same regex object in multiple nested frames in the same thread.  That's not a case that can be ignored--"I'm not doing that now" is something that will come back and bite you in the face a month later, when your code ends up recursing in ways you didn't originally think of.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a lot of these in one place, here's an alternative answer:

```
import re
class Matcher(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.matches = None
    def set(self, matches):
        self.matches = matches
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.matches, name)

class re2(object):
    def __init__(self, expr):
        self.re = re.compile(expr)

    def match(self, matcher, s):
        matches = self.re.match(s)
        matcher.set(matches)
        return matches

pattern = re2("(\d+)g")
m = Matcher()
if pattern.match(m, "123g"):
    print(m.group(1))
if not pattern.match(m, "x123g"):
    print "no match"
```

You can compile the regex once with the same thread safety as re, create a single reusable Matcher object for the whole function, and then you can use it very concisely.  This also has the benefit that you can reverse it in the obvious way--to do that with an iterator, you'd need to pass a flag to tell it to invert its result.

It's not much help if you're only doing a single match per function, though; you don't want to keep Matcher objects in a broader context than that; it'd cause the same issues as Blixt's solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really pretty-looking, but you can profit from the `getattr(object, name[, default])` built-in function using it like this:

```
>>> getattr(re.match("(\d+)g", "123g"), 'group', lambda n:'')(1)
'123'
>>> getattr(re.match("(\d+)g", "X23g"), 'group', lambda n:'')(1)
''
```

To mimic the *if match print group* flow, you can (ab)use the `for` statement this way:

```
>>> for group in filter(None, [getattr(re.match("(\d+)g", "123g"), 'group', None)]):
        print(group(1))
123
>>> for group in filter(None, [getattr(re.match("(\d+)g", "X23g"), 'group', None)]):
        print(group(1))
>>>
```

Of course you can define a little function to do the dirty work:

```
>>> matchgroup = lambda p,s: filter(None, [getattr(re.match(p, s), 'group', None)])
>>> for group in matchgroup("(\d+)g", "123g"):
        print(group(1))
123
>>> for group in matchgroup("(\d+)g", "X23g"):
        print(group(1))
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the perfect solution, but does allow you to chain several match options for the same str:

```
class MatchWrapper(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self._matcher = None

  def wrap(self, matcher):
    self._matcher = matcher

  def __getattr__(self, attr):
    return getattr(self._matcher, attr)

def match(pattern, s, matcher):
  m = re.match(pattern, s)
  if m:
    matcher.wrap(m)
    return True
  else:
    return False

matcher = MatchWrapper()
s = "123g";
if _match("(\d+)g", line, matcher):
  print matcher.group(1)
elif _match("(\w+)g", line, matcher):
  print matcher.group(1)
else:
  print "no match"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
import re

s = 'hello world'

match = []
if match.append(re.match('w\w+', s)) or any(match):
    print('W:', match.pop().group(0))
elif match.append(re.match('h\w+', s)) or any(match):
    print('H:', match.pop().group(0))
else:
    print('No match found')
```

You can use as many **elif** clauses as needed.

Even better:

```
import re

s = 'hello world'

if vars().update(match=re.match('w\w+', s)) or match:
    print('W:', match.group(0))
elif vars().update(match=re.match('h\w+', s)) or match:
    print('H:', match.group(0))
else:
    print('No match found')
```

Both **append** and **update** return **None**. So you have to actually check the result of your expression by using the **or** part in every case.

Unfortunately, this only works as long as the code resides top-level, i.e. not in a function.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do:

```
def re_match_cond (match_ref, regex, text):
    match = regex.match (text)
    del match_ref[:]
    match_ref.append (match)
    return match

if __name__ == '__main__':
    match_ref = []
    if re_match_cond (match_ref, regex_1, text):
        match = match_ref[0]
        ### ...
    elif re_match_cond (match_ref, regex_2, text):
        match = match_ref[0]
        ### ...
    elif re_match_cond (match_ref, regex_3, text):
        match = match_ref[0]
        ### ...
    else:
        ### no match
        ### ...
```

That is, I pass a list to the function to emulate pass-by-reference.